# What's the role of a centralized back-end on a dApp?

Tags: backend, blockchain, ethereum, decentralized-applications

I'm a bit puzzled on how a centralized back-end is integrated into the bigger picture of a back-end project, and googling has been of little help.

On a traditional CRUD back-end, it just receives requests from the front-end, normally queries a centralized database then returns the relevant data.

However, I am aware that a dApp doesn't necessarily need a back-end as the blockchain already acts as that.

So my question is basically, when is a centralized back-end needed or encouraged for a dApp?

As a follow-up, I'm also unsure on how the back-end is supposed to authenticate users. That is, is there a way to connect with Metamask and the likes to identify the user making requests?

A particular use-case I would like to explore is an NFT marketplace. What's the purpose of a back-end for something like that? I'm sure it'll be useful for saving user data not on the blockchain, but are blockchain-specific data also advisable to be store offchain?

Comment: Opensea for example makes you sign a message to authenticate with their backend. They also save things like your email and preferences.

Comment: @pguardiario, thanks. By the first, do you mean by using a JWT?

Comment: Yes probably a JWT

Comment: @pguardiario, how then is the private key for a particular address gotten? Passing it on or storing it on the backend doesn't seem secure.

Comment: You use the private key to sign the message, and their backend can verify that it was signed without knowing the private key

Comment: @pguardiario, okay I get it more clearly now. Thanks a lot. Do you have any link to a resource that also covers this? Finding resources on integrating traditional backends with blockchains has been surprisingly hard to find.

Comment: I found a blog post once but everything was out of date :(